# Accessing httpservletRequest attribute in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i am using Spring-MVC and posting data to the controller via ajax, and according to the business logic at controller i am returning different view.
the place i am got stuck is, i want to differentiate between the what kind of view is returned by controller in jquery and as we cannot access server objects in jquery, so this is creating problem.
below is the code of my controller and jquery.

The controller --

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mappedUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView someMethod(User dummyUser, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //Business logic here, Boolean status is returned according to it
    if (status) {
        return new ModelAndView("viewOne");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("info", "viewTwo");
        return new ModelAndView("viewTwo");
    }
}
```

ajax call --

```
 function submit(formId, Url) {
    var value = $("#" + formId).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        'type' : "POST",
        'cache' : false,
        'contentType' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'async' : false,
        'url' : Url,
        'data' : value,
        'success' : function(data) {
            //rendering view
        }
    });
   //NEED to determine here that which view was returned
}
```

Have tried setting attribute in controller and accessing it in jQuery but it didn't worked.Any Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can not access your HttpServletRequest from JavaScript. If you want to access any data from there, you have to add it to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some-how made a trick to distinguish between a view by setting an unique object as request attribute in `if part` on controller side and used it in the jsp(as hidden field) whose data is returned via ajax.

Afterwards, that field is simply accessed using jquery like -

```
if ($('#somehiddenElement').text().trim()) {
// if that request attribute is set then code in this block runs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access server's different scope objects in jquery or javascript. you should return your response as json or xml and consume your result in jquery or javascript. Spring MVC 3 has perfect combination with Jackson API to transform your objects into json

check following example

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.mkyong.common.model.Shop;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class JSONController {

@RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

    Shop shop = new Shop();
    shop.setName(name);
    shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

    return shop;

  }

}
```

check detail example in following link
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Comment: thanks for your reply, user solution works well if we are using json data in response... but we are bound to return the view from the controller as we are using tiles for view in our project architecture and we cannot change it.